How to Handle Nested Square Roots and Expressions in a Scientific Calculator App?
I'm developing an Android app called "Scientific Calculator" with Jetpack Compose, and I've successfully implemented the square root operation for simple cases like √4 and √4*2. However, I'm facing difficulties with handling more complex expressions such as √(1+2).
How can I modify my existing implementation to correctly handle and evaluate complex expressions involving nested square roots and parentheses? Any suggestions or improvements for the handleSqrtInput function and evaluate function would be greatly appreciated!
Current Implementation:

ViewModel (handleSqrtInput Function):

Functionality: This function handles input for the square root operation. It updates the display text based on the current context (e.g., appending √ or √().
private fun handleSqrtInput() {
    if (isResultDisplayed) {
        displayText = "√"
    } else {
        if (displayText == "0") {
            displayText = "√"
        } else if (displayText.isNotEmpty()) {
            val lastChar = displayText.last()

            when {
                lastChar.isDigit() -> {
                    try {
                        val res = Math.sqrt(displayText.toDouble())
                        displayText = res.toString()
                    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                        displayText = "Error"
                    }
                }
                lastChar == ')' -> {
                    try {
                        val res = Math.sqrt(displayText.toDouble())
                        displayText = res.toString() 
                    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                        displayText = "Error"
                    }
                }
                lastChar.toString().isOperator() -> {
                    displayText += "√"
                }
                lastChar == '(' -> {
                    displayText += "√"
                }
                lastChar == '√' -> {
                    displayText += "√"
                }
                else -> {
                    displayText = displayText.dropLast(1) + "√("
                }
            }
        } else {
            displayText = "√("
        }
    }
    isResultDisplayed = false
}



Model (evaluateExpression Function):

Functionality: Evaluates mathematical expressions, including square roots. This function parses the expression and uses stacks to manage operators and operands.
fun evaluate(expression: String): Double {
    val operators = Stack<Char>()
    val operands = Stack<Double>()

    var i = 0
    while (i < expression.length) {
        when {
            expression[i] == '√' -> {
                if (i + 1 < expression.length && expression[i + 1] == '(') {
                    operators.push(expression[i])
                } else {
                    i++
                    val sb = StringBuilder()
                    while (i < expression.length && (expression[i].isDigit() || expression[i] == '.' || expression[i] == '(' || expression[i] == ')')) {
                        sb.append(expression[i])
                        i++
                    }
                    val subExpr = sb.toString()
                    operands.push(sqrt(evaluate(subExpr)))
                    i--
                }
            }
        }
        i++
    }
    // Add additional logic for handling other operators and completing the expression evaluation
}


What I’m Trying to Achieve:
ViewModel:
Expected Outcome: Proper handling of square root operations, especially in complex expressions like √(1+3). The goal is to update the display and manage nested square roots effectively.
Model:
Expected Outcome: Correctly evaluate expressions involving square roots, including nested square roots. The aim is to parse and compute expressions like √(1+3) and √(√(12+4))accurately.

I strongly suggest not evaluating the expressions from string directly. Instead, write a parser function that transforms a string into a tree representing the expression. Then write a function that evaluates a tree into a value.

An alternative to using trees is using postfix notation, also called Reverse Polish Notation, which is much easier to handle than classic infix expressions. The infix expression √4*2 becomes the postfix expression 4 √ 2 *, which you can read as "4, take its root, 2, multiply them". The infix expression √(1+3) becomes the postfix expression 1 3 + √.

to explain why that's so useful: this lets you encode your math "phrases" using a simple stack. You push both operators and operands on, until you've covered the entire expression, then you start popping elements. If it's an operand, keep going, if it's an operator, run it on the operands you've popped so far and push the result back on the stack and restart. Repeat until your stack has a single element left, and that's the result of evaluating that math statement.
